# How to create a angular widget to be embedded in different websites?

Tags: javascript, angular, widget

I want to create a JS widget that can be embedded in different websites.

For example on some website there is a chat widget or a review widget.

My question is similar to another one, but with some details that a different. I would like to know if we can do it using **angular**.

Similar question: [How to architect a JS widget to be embedded in different websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72268661/how-to-architect-a-js-widget-to-be-embedded-in-different-websites)

---

For now I think using angular I would need to use an iframe, but in that case that would limit the features. For example the widget can create some functions usable everywere inside the website (ex: `MyWidget.show()` ), but inside an iframe I think it's not possible.

To make a renderer widget with angular, I think it would need to compile the angular module into one JS file that can be executed on every website.

**Main goal:** Create a simple angular component, and this component is shown be including a JS script inside another website.

How would you create the js file ?

Answer (score 2):

Angular application (a widget so to say) could be built using ahead of time compilation. The application (compacted js file) can then be used externally by other javascript files.

> An Angular application consists mainly of components and their HTML templates. Because the components and templates provided by Angular cannot be understood by the browser directly, Angular applications require a compilation process before they can run in a browser. The Angular ahead-of-time (AOT) compiler converts your Angular HTML and TypeScript code into efficient JavaScript code during the build phase before the browser downloads and runs that code.

https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

So using `ng build --prod` you will get 4-5 js files `main.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js etc.` You could import these to your other JS project for usage.

Alternatively, you could use 3rd party libraries that pack all these files into a single js file (`ngx-build-plus` https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus) For example, you could create an Angular component and use it in React.

---

On `ng build --prod --single-bundle` your Angular project will be built into single bundle

Build command:

```json
ng build --prod --single-bundle
```

React js now consumes this via `<script>` tags (or import it).

```html
<script src="./my-angular-in-single-file.js"></script>
```

If your planning to use Angular components in other Angular projects I would advise creating reusable components by packaging them and consuming them via npm, for example.

There are downsides in compacting everything into a single file of course - the download size for example.